# Is there a short hand method of retrieving a value from a function in an insert?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tsqlt

I have some tSQLt tests which are using magic numbers for some static data IDs and I'm trying to make them more self documenting by using a function.

Currently I'm using this but it's a bit more wordy than I would like and was hoping there was a short form method I could use without the extra brackets around the function. I know I could do this more efficiently by declaring the Ids as variables but as this is for tests my priority is more on the readability/self-documenting side.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tAccessProfileAreaRight (id, AccessProfileId, AccessAreaRightId)
VALUES (1, 1, (SELECT dbo.GetAccessAreaRightId('Purchase Orders', 'Authorise'))),
       (2, 1, (SELECT dbo.GetAccessAreaRightId('Purchase Invoices', 'Authorise'))),
```

Comment: Why do you feel `dbo.GetAccessAreaRightId('Purchase Orders', 'Authorise')` would be more readable/ self documenting than just using a sufficiently verbose variable name?

Comment: With a large list of values it would separate the setting of the variables from their usage, ideally this would be over come with good naming however devs have a tendency to use short hand. 
With the retrieval done in ine the retrieved value is linked directly to the descriptions in the same line so devs are less likely to ignore the helper methods and just use the magic numbers or to modify an AccessAreaRightId to get another. It's also nice that SSMS by default highlights strings in bright red but not variables.

Answer (score 2):

You want your test to be more readable with is a great goal to aim at. However, your chosen way might not be optimal.

In general, a test should insert the data needed for the test in all tables accessed by the code under test. So in this case I suggest you insert a row into `dbo.tAccessAreaRight` and a row into `dbo.tAccessProfile` before inserting into `dbo.tAccessProfileAreaRight`.

To not be hindered by existing or potential future constraints on the tables, use `tSQLt.FakeTable`.

That would make your test look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyTestClass.[test ... is doing ... when ...]
AS
BEGIN
  -- Assemble
  exec tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.tAccessProfileAreaRight'
  exec tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.tAccessAreaRight'
  exec tSQLt.FakeTable 'dbo.tAccessProfile'

  INSERT INTO dbo.tAccessProfile(id) VALUES (1042); 
  INSERT INTO dbo.tAccessAreaRight(id) VALUES (5013),(5017); 

  INSERT INTO dbo.tAccessProfileAreaRight(id, AccessProfileId, AccessAreaRightId)
    VALUES(1,1042,5013),
          (1,1042,5017);
  
  --Act
  INSERT INTO #SomeTableThatYouNeedToCreateFirst
  EXEC dbo.ProcedureUnderTest @AccessProfileId=1042

  --Assert

  --do what you need to do to make sure the code behaves correctly, 
  --for example using EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable
END
GO
```

Because we are using `tSQLt.FakeTable` you do not need to worry about the columns you do not need, so in the three inserts above, just include the columns that are actually accessed by the code under test. For that same reason, you do want to explicitly list the columns, even if you end up using all columns in a table. That way, if an unrelated piece of functionality requires an additional column in the table later on, this test will be unaffected by that change.

I find this pattern leads to not only more immediately understandable tests, as for each "magic number," it is clear where it came from; you also make your test independent of an unrelated piece of code that at some point might change or just stop being maintained which could lead to random test failures, something we should strive to avoid.

Comment: tAccessAreaRight contains static data held in source control so I don't want to seed it with data as that doesn't really add any benefit and could cause issues if there is business logic tied to some of the values.
tAccessProfileAreaRight and tAccessProfile are already fake tables but that's not really in the scope of the question.

Comment: Another way of dealing with magic numbers is to give them names. In T-SQL that would mean to assign the value to a variable with a descriptive name and then use that variable later on in the test. If you do only need one or two of those values, that should make the test more readable. At some point, you get diminishing ROI on that, though.

Comment: Yeah, I did consider that but the way the default syntax highlighting works using inline function calls 'pops' better. Also it avoids potential issues around naming conventions for the variables and discourages devs doing things like @WriteAccessId + 1

Answer (score -1):

You could do an Insert Into with a Select.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tAccessProfileAreaRight (id, AccessProfileId, AccessAreaRightId)
select 1,1,dbo.GetAccessAreaRightId('Purchase Orders', 'Authorise')
UNION select 2,1,dbo.GetAccessAreaRightId('Purchase Invoices', 'Authorise')
UNION select ...
```

Also you don't have to specify the columns for the INSERT INTO if the select columns match the table columns exactly.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tAccessProfileAreaRight
select 1,1,dbo.GetAccessAreaRightId('Purchase Orders', 'Authorise')
UNION select 2,1,dbo.GetAccessAreaRightId('Purchase Invoices', 'Authorise')
```

Comment: Just because you can leave out the columns in the insert list doesn’t mean you should. This is an invisible potential future bug should the table or the query change. Also, why UNION? I would use UNION ALL because it seems like the intention is to insert two rows, even if they are the same, but they can’t be anyway, so it’s extra work for nothing (and proliferates a common tendency to use a bad default behavior because it’s fewer characters).

Comment: I agree with Aaron in regards that not including column names in the "Insert Into" isn't the best approach for live code (testing or production) . If it's for documentation then maybe it's okay as readability is important but code that breaks will be far worse. The UNION ALL isn't required (Union will eliminate duplicates whereas UNION ALL will include all records even if they are duplicates) as he mentioned b/c you have different IDs (first column) and I assume different results since the functions have different values in them.

Comment: But my point was that _even if the results are the same_ the OP’s intent was to insert two rows. Don’t change their intent and the behavior of the query by introducing a UNION (which is similar to adding a DISTINCT they didn’t have).

Comment: Also for me documentation is not a good place to promote lazy practices either. :-)

Comment: The OP never stated they were inserting only two rows so that's an assumption on your part. Just like I assumed there are more than two rows of data being inserted since there is a comma after the last VALUES line (indicating a continuation of the values). We can only garner as much info the poster provides and this is snippet of code that doesn't give us the whole scope so there are a lot of "assumptions" being made by everyone. Regardless, it's important to know that UNION and UNION ALL are different and they should be used in a specific way.

Comment: I am looking at their existing statement and they are inserting two rows. By adding UNION you’ve made an assumption that has the potential to _change_ behavior (rather silently), while I’ve made an assumption that _doesn’t_ change behavior. And I bring it up because after 25+ years in SQL Server I see UNION thrown around all over the place when 99% of the time UNION ALL would have been fine (and perform better). A bug in logic even at small scale (this returned duplicates when it shouldn’t have!) is easier to spot than “this eliminated rows” or “wow this is slower!”

Comment: I could but the real aim here is to make the code as readable as possible and this seems more complex to read